# dconf-service extensive io (write) on any key press

Tags: 15.10, io

Fresh Ubuntu 15.10 installation on my home server PC.
I noticed that `dconf-service` performs constant file creation and writes (?) to config files in home dir of current user on any key press.

`iotop` tool says that such extensive io is only performed by that process.

`lsof` shows me the path where those files are created and then removed:

> ~/.config/dconf

Created files are similar to `user.RV14AY`. Only 1 such file present at given moment and removed after small delay.

If I press and hold any key, then this leads to constant HDD writes. Also at that moment `unity-settings-daemon` process starts to consume a lot of CPU (but not io).

I am connected to my server via NoMachine remote desktop. Server does not have hardware keyboard so I can't test it that way.

Any idea how to 'fix' this issue?

Comment: I can confirm the behavior of `dconf-service`. For me, it also happens when clicking/tapping with the touchpad. Happens on a 6 year old notebook with physical keyboard and MATE. This bug (or some form of it) seems to be present since a long while (see [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/d-conf/+question/178204) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/d-conf/+bug/1463243) ).

Answer (score 2):

Hint, after dealing with my own dconf-service excessive IO pains ... which brought down my machine due to excessive disk thrashing for 6 months .... grumble ....

type this in the console to watch dconf traffic in real time, which might tell you which application is misbehaving. In my case, compiz and unity weren't getting along and clobbering eachothers configs ...

> dconf watch /

forward slash means you want to monitor the whole tree ...

Comment: edit, fix was to use ccsm to rebuild the config. Switched the storage backend to flatfile and then back to GSettings (dconf)